# Tab Index is Reset in UpdatePanel

Tags: asp.net, html, vb.net, updatepanel, tabindex

I'm currently having an issue where an updatepanel does an async postback and loses the tab order when the partial postback occurs.

When you run through the tabs the tab order works correctly, but then you press a button and the partial postback occures the tabindex is reset. Is there any non-javascript solution to this. If not, what would the javascript solution be?

Comment: When you say the "tabindex is reset", do you mean that the focus is no longer on the button in your update panel?

Comment: Patmortech - yes the focus goes back to the item that has a tab index of 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try putting this at the end of the code that is handling your button click event:

```
ScriptManager.SetFocus(DirectCast(sender, Control))
```

This would put the focus back on your button when the page loads.

Answer (score 0):

this is a fix for anyone using AutoPostBack="true" on controls not going to the next control in the tab order.  if you wrap each control in it's own UpdatePanel the focus will move to the next control as expected.  even w/ UpdateMode="Conditional" the controls seem to lose focus.  i hope this helps someone else.